# How to switch between variable sets without having to load a new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multilingual

I am using PHP and JS / jQuery to create a multilingual one-page site.

Only a few pieces of text are going to be interchangeable, but there is no reason to make the user reload the entire page with images.

Below you can see there are three variables: 
1. imgVar
2. titleVar
3. textVar

imgVar won't change, but titleVar and textVar will be different depending on the language selected.

Also, this piece of code will need to be run as a foreach loop, because there will be multiple instances of this.

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/portfolio/**imgVar**.jpg" alt="" />
            <h4><span> **titleVar** </span></h4>
            <div class="portfolio-text">
            <p><span> **textVar** </span></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I'm not sure what the best way to organize the sets of variables (maybe JSON? or PHP arrays?) or whether what I'm trying to do is even possible, especially without reloading the page.

I know I will most likely use AJAX but I can't add the jQuery *load* function onto anything but HTML, which won't allow me to write the PHP foreach loop.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: sounds like a jquery feature to show/hide divs on selection ?

Comment: is simply javascript function a choice for you?

Comment: You can use jquery's function load. Make a div with id (let's say 'reload') that starts before the for loop of php and ends after the loop. This way from javascript you will be able to reload everything that is in div with id 'reload'

Comment: AJAX does not load a new page. As long as you are not trying to alter a non-primative value you should be fine with reassignment.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at vue.js or angular. You can do something like `{{ titleVar[lang] }}` and both vue and angular will refresh parts of page without reloading.

Answer (score -1):

The goal would be to 'query' your database to display this information. Doing so like below with a PDO connection...

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());
$Query = $q->fetchAll();
```

You could cheat and run it as a 'function'

```
function mySwitch($Title,$Text,$Image) {
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/portfolio/<?php echo $Image; ?> .jpg" alt="" />
            <h4><span><?php echo $Title; ?> </span></h4>
            <div class="portfolio-text">
            <p><span><?php echo $Text; ?> </span></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
}
```

then you can wrap it in a forward loop

```
foreach ($Query as $row) {
echo mySwitch($row['row'],$row['columnhere'],$row['columnhere']);
}
```

which should display

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/portfolio/Image252.jpg" alt="" />
    <h4><span>My Title here</span></h4>
    <div class="portfolio-text">
    <p><span>Text goes here </span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I will find myself doing something similar every now and then especially when I have duplicating code; Makes it simple and easy to get across. Also debugging is clean/easy to read.

This is untested as a FYI.